# Howto send out UDP packets, on different frequency [802.11p - 5.875 GHz]

Tags: java, android

I need to send out packets on a different frequency, not on normal 2.4GHz.
Has anyone tried that before and knows how to do it?

Would be nice, if anyone can give me a hint.

Best Regards.

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve by controlling the frequency that the packets are sent out on?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11p

Comment: Now I'm more confused.  You're suggesting he wants to use a different spectrum than the 802.11b/g radio in his Android device?

Comment: I started working with car2car wireless boxes which are working on that frequency. I thought it might be possible to communicate with them through my android mobile. It's for my final theses...

Comment: If the device supported it - yes.  I really doubt it does, though, as I really doubt you'll be able to expose the functionality in whatever drivers the device has on it.  Best of luck, though.

Answer (score 2):

If your Android device could communicate via 802.11p (it requires a specific radio/antenna combination), the 802.11p device would be a specific network interface. You could then, assuming you had an IP stack running on that interface, send out UDP packets on it.

If your Android device doesn't have an 802.11p radio, there's no way to turn an 802.11a/b/g radio into one.

Answer (score 2):

Transmitting a packet implies that you already have, at very least, a transport layer established. It is not possible to transmit packets on arbitrary frequencies without first establishing a transport. Check out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osi_model

In other words, you would first need to establish an 802.11p session with a wireless access point before you could transmit packets.

You cannot force a device which does not support 802.11p to connect with it. Devices are manufactured with specific chips to enable wireless communications, and are limited to the protocols supported by that chip.

You might be interested in this JSR:
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=307

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question.

You can definitely change the card settings through a variety of ways to change the frequency, then send all traffic out on that frequency.

I don't think there is any possible way to send a specific number of packets out on a specific frequency while other traffic maintains the original frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. WiFi only works in either 2.4GHz frequency mode of 5GHz (which is not enables on most phones, because it's very battery-hungry). <strike>What you might not understand is that 2.4GHz is *not* the frequency you're sending signals on, but rather the full bandwidth of your wireless communication range.</strike> There 11 channels inside the 2.4G bandwidth that run on different frequencies, "modulated away from the 2.4 GHz center frequency", but only practically three of them (1, 6, and 11) run on non-overlapping frequency ranges.

The channel on which you are doing it is set the the wireless access point (such as a wireless router) and *not* the device. I suggest you look up the IEEE 802.11 standard as @Jonathon suggested.

Comment: No, the bandwidth is only 22MHz. The band is 2.4GHz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels

Comment: @Gabe, I take it back. You're right = ) I was somewhat misinformed. I looked it up just before you posted you second comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way around the fact that the phone itself doesn't have the radio hardware to broadcast on the 802.11p frequencies would be to build a small device that accepts Bluetooth or Wifi and rebroadcasts data using 802.11p hardware.

That may be a bit more than you want to get into, though.